# Bound for function with constant /periodic second derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, periodic-functions

Consider a function $f : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f''$ continuous and $f''(x)=f''(x+1)$ for all real numbers x.
I need to show that there exists a real positive number $c$ such that $f(x)\leq c(1+x^2)$ for all real numbers $x$. I feel like this might come from Taylor expansion of the function but any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Since $f''$ is periodic you can expand it in a Fourier series. Then you can integrate twice and arrive at a result featuring a constant term, terms proportional to $x$ and $x^2$ and a remainder that is periodic.

Comment: if you are afraid of Fourier series, just consider $g(x)$ such that $g'(x) = f''(x) - C$ where $C = \int_0^1 f''(x) dx$. what can you say about $g(x+1) - g(x)$ ? and about $|g(x)|$ as $x \to \infty$ ?

Comment: thanks, g(x+1)-g(x) is a constant? Thank you also Urgje, I have tried using fourier series but have just come into difficulty finding the coefficients

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\left(\int_0^xf'(y)dy\right)+f(0)=\left(\int_0^x\left(\left(\int_0^y f''(z)dz\right)+f'(0)\right)dy\right)+f(0)$$
If $f''$ is periodic and continuous, then it is bounded hence $|f''(x)|\leq b$ for a $b\geq 0$ and we get
$$f(x)\leq|f(x)|\leq  \left(\int_0^x\left(\left(\int_0^y b \ dz\right)+|f'(0)|\right)dy\right)+|f(0)|\\= \left(\int_0^x by+|f'(0)|dy\right)+|f(0)|=
\frac{b}{2}x^2+|f'(0)|x+|f(0)|$$
Define $c:= \max(b/2,|f(0)|)+|f'(0)|$ and we get
$$f(x)\leq c(1+x^2).$$

Comment: ah and the boundedness comes from it being continuous on [0,1] compact, so its bounded everywhere, thats what i was missing, thank you!